# Did the internal combustion engine exist in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was curious if there was ever a power source similar to the real life internal combustion rngine, but all I've been able to find is a single line article on [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Internal-combustion). Can anyone expand if this is the same sort of engine?

I will accept Legends and canon answers.

Comment: Are the two links on wookieepedia (Star Wars: The Roleplaying Game + Heir to the Empire Sourcebook) not good enough for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combustion engines do receive a couple of mentions in the the EU, notably in the RPG sourcebooks and at least one novel

> Lando and Vuffi Raa followed the right wall, which curved gently into the vast circularity that was the chamber of the Mindharp. By the time the figures on the wall were playing with internal combustion engines and rocketry, the pair had only walked a few dozen meters. Uncounted thousands of centuries of history lay ahead of them.
>
> <sub><sup>[Lando Calrissian and the Mindharp of Sharu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lando_Calrissian_and_the_Mindharp_of_Sharu)</sup></sub>

For the record, the Star Wars universe is one where convenient space-faring civilisation has been around for more than 20,000 years and repulsor technology for even longer. These technologies are widespread and mature, even on poorly contacted worlds and can be understood and applied by anyone with the capacity to make something as complex as a motorcar, in the same way that Ford could (should the mood take them) make a coal-powered steam car with stone wheels.